# How to get data from NOSQL database and display it in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, nosql

new to React! I am building a React application, which is currently using a rest api to get data from another website using the fetch function, as shown below. I am displaying the results in a ag-grid. Now I have been told that the data is actually migrating to a NOSQL database and they want me to find a way to fire a SPARQL query and display the data in the same way. How can I possibly do that?

What I am using so far is this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('this/is/my/api/here', {
        method: 'get',
        },
      })
     .then(result => result.json())
     .then(rowData => this.setState({rowData}))
     }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
          rowData={this.state.rowData}>
        </AgGridReact>
      </div>
```